# Change Moto X's Google Now Voice

Tags: google-now, moto-x

I'm Mexican but I really hate the Spanish voice that my Moto X uses by default, is there any way I can change it to English?

Answer (score 0):

Look up Ivona Text to speech in the play store. They have at least one secondary Spanish voice.

Comment: Turns out that although I can change Motorola's TT voice (which it's Spanish voice I like), I can't change the one Google Now uses.